# Regex for everything in quotations only if certain string appears

Tags: regex

for example i have two lines

```
" dswda__12 ( Linux, 22 ) sasa "
```

and

```
" dshbjsd12_22 ( Windows, 21 ) sws "
```

I want to match everything insides quotes for only line with word containing Linux using regex pattern only,

Im only new and have tried `((["'][.*])(\<Linux\>)([.*]["']))` however cant figure it out

Answer (score 0):

What are your constraints exactly? Do quotes have to be part of the match?
Matching line with `Linux` is straightforward:

```
.*Linux.*
```

Note that it is case sensitive.
You can add more elements and be more specific though.
Also what language do you use?

You can test expressions here: https://regex101.com/r/01R4b2/1

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern should work:

```
['"](.*Linux.*)['"]
```

The first and last `['"]` are used to match opening and closing quotation marks (single or double). The `.*` before and after the word `Linux` is to match everything inside the quotation marks that surrounds the word `Linux`. The braces `(` and `)` are to capture the part inside the quotation marks only.

Here's the test using your example inputs: http://regexr.com/633sg